# Is it possible to construct a NOT gate if given only OR gates and XOR gates?

Tags: digital-logic

I was given this problem and I don't think it is possible since if both inputs are zero on a OR gate or a XOR gate, all outputs will be zero.  Or am I wrong here?

Comment: As a hint think about what happens with each gate if you tie one input low or high. Both the inputs don't have to be tied together.

Comment: Have you assembled truth tables for all three gates yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Virtually any gate is possible so long as you have a 2 input gate with the capability for inversion.

Take a closer look at an XOR gate truth table and you should be able to see how to do it:

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|}
\hline A & B & OUT \\
\hline 0 & 0 & 0 \\  
\hline 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\hline 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
\hline 
\end{array}

I'll give you just the opposite of what you want even to show you how it works:
Set B to 0 and what do you get?

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|}
\hline A & B & OUT \\
\hline 0 & 0 &  0  \\
\hline 1 & 0 &  1  \\
\hline 
\end{array}
What'd that do to the truth table and **A**? It turned it into a pass/buffer gate. Whatever comes in **A** is exactly what comes out.

Comment: Ahhh... I don't realize I could use 0 or 1 as constants.  I was only thinking in variables only.

Comment: @vxs8122 - You can derive constants from gates as well. Think of a NOT gate with both inputs connected to the output - it will always output 0.

Comment: @ConnorWolf I've never heard of a NOT gate with two inputs. What exactly do you speak of?

Comment: @horta - Arrrgh, typo, I meant XOR, and had a brain-fart.

Comment: @ConnorWolf Ah gotcha. Np, we all have them.

Comment: @ConnorWolf: Given AND, OR, and XOR gates alone, one could easily derive an inverter given a "constant high", or derive a constant high if given an inverter, and could derive an "AND NOT" function even without any of those things, but unless given one of those things one couldn't define NAND, NOR, XNOR, or any other gate whose output would be high when all the inputs were low.

Comment: @ConnorWolf: Such a distinction is not merely theoretical; it's sometimes necessary to perform certain logic functions without any source of power other than the inputs themselves, and it's not possible for such logic to make something out of nothing.